# Trying to insert CKEditor 5 but two text editors show on the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ckeditor

Two text editors are appearing on the page, the basic one and the more updated version. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can anybody help?

```html
        <script src="../../assets/js/ckeditor5/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <script>
          ClassicEditor.create(document.getElementById('body'));
        </script>
```

```html
                        <div>
                            <label>Body</label>
                            <textarea name="body" id="body"><?php echo $body ?></textarea>
                        </div>
```

The second text editor (the updated version) isn't saving the content I put into it, only the top editor sends through the data to my database. Proper confused, apologies if it's a simple fix, head is mashed.

Cheers!

Comment: According to the "docs" they want you to create your dom element as a `div` *not* a `textarea`. See https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/quick-start.html